# Can a vector space containing zero vector be linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A vector space usually contains zero vector. Now a set containing zero vector cannot be linearly independent since for set
S= {v1,v2,..., vr,... vn} , vr being zero vector

0v1+0v2+0v3+....+avr+....+0vn=0

a!=0(I.e. a not equal to zero)

This implies that set S is linearly dependent. 
This means that , a vector space containing zero vector should also be linearly dependent.

Am I thinking right? Also do we care about its linearly independence or dependence ?

Please clear my confusion.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes and no. A vector space, *as a set*, cannot be linearly independent since it contains lots of linearly dependent vectors ($v$ and $-v$ for instance). But it contains lots of linearly independent subsets.

Comment: a vector space it doesn't have to be infinite dimensional  in order to talk about linear dependence or independence. For exaple the set $\{(0,1),(1,0)\} $is a linearly independent subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: There is no vector space without zero vector, so... The zero vector doesnt belong to the field, it is a vector, not an scalar. Of course the field have their zero.

Comment: @masacroso, yes you are right. I meant to say zero being scalar of field multiplies with any vector of vector space , which gives zero vector and it must belong to vector space since vector space is closed under scalar multiplication.isn't it?

Comment: @KaSikh No, a vector space has a zero vector by definition. You can't show that the zero scalar of a field multiplied by a vector is the zero vector if you don't even declare the existence of a zero vector. If you don't declare a zero vector exists, I don't even know what additive inverses of vectors do.

Answer (score 1):

The zero vector belongs to the vector space, but linear independence is not about which vectors belong to the whole space, but to the list you're studying. If a particular list of vectors contains the $0$ vector, it cannot be linearly independent, as you say. On the other hand, every vector space must contain the $0$ vector, and we're not talking about linear independence of the entire vector space as a set itself, just some given vectors.

In short, when dealing with questions of linear independence, all that matters are the given vectors in the set, not the whole space. You're asking about non-trivial solutions to the linear equation $\sum a_i v_i = 0$ for some given $v_i$.

Comment: So you mean, we never say that a vector space is linearly dependent or independent.

Comment: No, what Alfred said about that is wrong (and strange). Linear independence/dependence is regarding a subset of a vector space $V$. In particular, $V \subseteq V$, so it's perfectly reasonable to ask if $V$ is linearly dependent or linearly independent. There is nothing about the definition that "bans" us from asking about the whole space. However, since we know that $0 \in V$, and that any set that contains the $0$ vector is linearly dependent, we can now conclude that any vector space is linearly dependent.

Comment: What? What I said is fine. We do not talk about vector spaces being linearly independent. We talk about sets of vectors as being linearly independent.